# substr_replace и отформатированный текст

Tags: php

Вот у нас есть код, допустим (текст в $var может меняться и там могут появляться другие теги, не только 'a', а может быть, что и вовсе там их не будет):

```
$var = "slovo <a href='hashcode.ru'>slovo</a> slovo";
echo substr_replace($var, 'bob', 8, 0) . "<br />\n";
```

В итоге substr_replace нарушит html тег "a" и влезет в него. Получится такая каша:

```
slovo <abobashcode.ru'>slovo</a> slovo<br />
```

Как сделать, чтобы временно убрать форматирование из текста, а затем, когда substr_replace завершит работу, обратно поставить все теги форматирования. Проще говоря, как получить такой результат:

```
slovo <a href='hashcode.ru'>slovo</a>bob slovo
```

Примечание: нужно вставлять текст после закрывающего html тега, какой бы он ни был.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Т.к. мне это нужно было для Wordpress, то и решение я нашел среди уже готовых:

```
the_excerpt();
```

Еще, как вариант, можно использовать explode с разделением абзацев. И в конец первого абзаца вставлять нужный текст, затем заменить новый текст на старый.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать вот так:

> ```
> $var = "slovo";
> $slovo = substr_replace($var, 'bob', 1, 0);
> echo "$var <a href='hashcode.ru'>$slovo</a> $var";
> ```

Comment: текст в $var может меняться и там могут появляться другие теги, не только 'a', а может быть, что и вовсе там их не будет

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы вам для начала не найти позицию вхождения данного слова("bob") в исходную строку, используя функцию **"strpos()"**, а уже затем, используя функцию **"substr_replace()"**:

> ```
> $var = "slovo <a href='hashcode.ru'>slovo</a> slovo";
> $pos = strpos($var,"bob");
> echo substr_replace($var, 'bob', $pos, mb_strlen("bob")) . "<br />\n";
> ```